# Value of MatRadioGroup is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button

I'm having trouble accessing the value of radio buttons. This is my code:

```
      <mat-radio-group #rangeInput>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" value="5">5</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" value="7" [checked]="true">7</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" value="9">9</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
      <button mat-raised-button [matDialogClose] (click)="onInput(rangeInput.value)">Ok</button>
```

It seems like the mat-radio-group elementref doesn't have a value property?! What am I doing wrong?

Greetings Fonzane

Comment: Hi, did you checked it offical angular material document : https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

Comment: Yes, here is a quote: "The radio-group has a value property that reflects the currently selected radio-button inside of the group."

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngModel` on radiogroup

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="rangeValue">
        <mat-radio-button name="range" [value]="3">3</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" [value]="5">5</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" [value]="7" [checked]="true">7</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="range" value="9">9</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<button mat-raised-button [matDialogClose] (click)="onInput()">Ok</button>
```

TS:

```
rangeValue:any;

onInput(){
  //use this.rangeValue here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did work. But the checked property now doesn't work anymore o_O

Comment: yes, for that initialize rangeValue to 7 like: `rangeValue = 7`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

**app.component.ts**

```
 onDataChange(event) {
  console.log(event.value);    
 }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" (change)="onDataChange($event)">
<mat-radio-button name="range" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button name="range" value="5">5</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button name="range" value="7" [checked]="true">7</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button name="range" value="9">9</mat-radio-button>
```